# Django: how to take input as range and store it in the database?

Tags: django

I am beginner in Django and thinking to create a website that asks the user for input (the input here is an hour range) and store it in the data base
e.g. A slider that ranges from 5am till 9pm the user can set the start and end for example 7am-9am and submit it and then it will be stored in the database

I am not sure how to approach it. Also, how will it be stored in the database as a single entry or multiple entries? Your help is much appreciated.

I have been trying continuously to search for tutorials, videos, articles, even any piece of information here and there that could give me the kickstart but I failed

Comment: use multiple columns (say)  'start_time'   and   'end_time', check database normalizations

Comment: You should actually create another website yourself and learn how to use django first. Once you do that, you'll know how and where to start in this project of yours.

Comment: This question is too broad / several questions.

Comment: If you are willing to restrict yourself to Postgres, it offers you a DateTimeRangeField. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/